# How to use \graphicspath + epstopdf OR \graphicspath + latex => ps => pdf

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps, epstopdf

Background: I am using MikTek and TeXnicCenter. Since I am using Windows, I have to deal with folders whose names have spaces, such as `C:/Documents and Settings/...` and I use `\usepackage[space]{grffile}` to deal with this problem.

Problem: I saved a bunch of EPS figures in a folder and I use the `\graphicspath` to specify that folder in my LaTeX document. I tried to things to get a PDF with pictures:

1. If I use the package `epstopdf` then it doesn´t know that it must save the PDF version of the figure in that folder, and it just complains that it cannot find the figure. It ends up producing a PDF file without pictures.
2. If I use LaTeX => PS => PDF compilation, then it complains it cannot find the figure, but shows it anyway (!?). The problem is that it displays the picture in a chaotic manner. puts all the pictures I try to load in the first page. (this is a document with several pages, and pictures).

Attempted solutions:

1. If I write a short LaTeX file in my pictures folder with the `epstopdf` package, then it saves a PDF version of my pictures in that folder. Later, when I try to compile the document I am trying to produce, it works just fine. But that is a hassle...

Comment: Please provide more detail as to what you use for `\graphicspath` in your document preamble. For example, what type of images do you have (`JPEG`, `PNG`, `EPS`, `PDF`, ...)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712681/how-to-use-graphicspath-epstopdf-or-graphicspath-latex-ps-pdf?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: It's normally not a good idea to use absolute paths for external files, either on Windows or elsewhere. `\graphicspath` is best used for subdirectories of the one containing the main `.tex` file, which can be done in a relative sense, while for other cases `TEXINPUTS` can be used.